# How to resolve Add-PnPGroupMember adding users to wrong groups with same names?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am using Add-PnPGroupMember to add a list of users to a SharePoint group using PowerShell script.

Assume there are two SharePoint sites A and B. A and B both have a subsite called C. So, the URLs of both the sites will be like this:

**https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/A/C
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/B/C**

Both these sites have a group with the same name called **C Members**.

I ran a PowerShell script to add a list of users to the group **C Members** of site A/C, but it adds it to the group in B/C.

I am really confused by the results of this and not able to reproduce this issue again.

Sharing a part of the code that I ran, if that helps. Please provide your feedback, as to what can be the reason of this outcome.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/A/C" -UseWebLogin -WarningAction Ignore

Add-PnPGroupMember -Group "C Members" -EmailAddress $User -SendEmail
```

This script loops through a number of sites and corresponding users to be added. After this script was executed, unexpectedly, the user was added to the site B/C instead of A/C.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Please try specifying the group ID instead of the group name when adding members. You can get the group ID using Get-PnPGroup and specifying the group name and site URL:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/A/C" -UseWebLogin -WarningAction Ignore

$group = Get-PnPGroup -Identity "C Members" -Site "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/A/C"
Add-PnPGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id -EmailAddress $User -SendEmail
```

This should ensure that the users are added to the correct group, even if there are groups with the same name on different sites.